# Subsets of positive measure in a group

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

Let $G$ be a Lie group (maybe LCH and second countable topological group is enough here) and $\mu$ be a Borel probability measure on $G$ (not necessarily Haar). Suppose $U$ is an open subset of $G$ of positive measure. I wonder if the follow assertion is true:

> There exists open subsets $V,W$ of positive measure such that $VW\subset U$.

My thoughts: certainly I can find open subsets $V,W$ with $VW\subset U$ by the continuity of the multiplication, but I don't see whether $V,W$ have positive measure.

Comment: I think you can do this using regularity

Comment: @MathQED sorry I don't see how to use the regularity here. Can you say something more?

Comment: Nevermind my comment. I think it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $G$ to be the real line and any measure supported on the interval $U=(100,101)$.  If your two sets $V$ and $W$ have positive measure their sum is not contained in $U$.

Comment: A comment for myself: if the measure is supported on the interval $=(100,101)$ then any positive subsets $V,W$ must intersect $(100,101)$ and the sum will exceed 200

Comment: That is precisely it!